# iOS: Animation view moves back to original position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to make an animation with a view to simply move up the Y axis by about 50 points.
The animation works, but as soon as its done, it will return back to its original position.

```
UIView* view = [self.view viewWithTag:50];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         CGRect frame = view.frame;
         frame.origin.y = 230;
         frame.origin.x = 30;
         view.frame = frame;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSLog(@"Completed");

     }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout constraints will be pulling it back. This is a really common question at the moment. You have to modify your NSLayoutConstraint objects to reflect the change to the view.

E.g. Constraint.constant += 50;

Search stack overflow for other questions like the one you want to ask before asking.

Comment: Oops, all my google searches led me to outdated answers. I got it working though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, constraints need to be changed and updated in the the animation as seen below:

```
- (IBAction)moveAction:(id)sender {
    self.spaceConstraint.constant += 220;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
         [self.imageView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```